# Removing duplicate code from code single/two-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, code-duplication

I'm currently facing a problem where I use an Array that contains other Arrays. Underneath is my current code. The problem however is that I execute 100 times the same code, only difference is the $anotherOtherIndex that I need for when I loop over an Array that is inside the Array I loop for.

It would help me a lot if somebody would have solution to reduce the amount of code needed, by eliminating the duplicate code.

```
for( $index = 0; $index < $endOfLoop; $index++ ) {        
            if(true) {
                $myVariable = arrayWithArrays[$index][$anotherIndex]
                x100...
            }else{
                $myVariable = arrayWithArrays[$index][$anotherIndex][$anotherOtherIndex]
                x100...
}
```

Psuedo-code solution ( that would be perfect, and we all now perfect doesn't exist ;) ):

```
for( $index = 0; $index < $endOfLoop; $index++ ) {        
            $myVariable = arrayWithArrays[$index][$anotherIndex][?????]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the main part and only go further into the array on the condition

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $endOfLoop; $i++ ) {        
    $myVariable = arrayWithArrays[$index][$anotherIndex]

    if(false) {
        $myVariable = $myVariable[$anotherOtherIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: This does improve my code, since there is no else statement anymore. However, I still end up with 100 lines of code that are for 90% the exact same ;(

Comment: Can you show what the next few repetitions are and it may be easier to understand where further repetition can be removed (if possible)

Comment: I can, but it's exactly the same as the example. Only difference is that in my code there are different (more unclear) variable names.